# change onclick even to autocall

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have radio button input onclick named 
    onclick="shippingMethodStep.save()" 
when someone clicked it it will add my shipping cost to my grand total billing in pagecheckout.

I want function "shippingmethodstep.save()" automaticly called without click the radio

here is the radio button code :

```
<input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> onclick="shippingMethodStep.save()"/>
```

I already search and try to call it automaticly by change onclick to onload or add shippingMethodStep.save() but it doesn't work. I think I put the script wrong because I am very newbie to javascript.

can you please give advice for this.

thanks

Comment: Why can't you just call `shippingMethodStep.save()` directly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to call shippingmethodstep.save() when the page loads?

> /* javascript */
>   window.onload = shippingmethodstep.save();
>
> /* jQuery */
>   $(document).ready( shippingmethodstep.save() );